# My Formspree contact form isn't sending out the email information

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, email

I have been using formspree on one of my sites. Everything was working fine at first then the form messages weren't sending out emails. I see the name and the message when the form is sent out, but the email just isn't registering. I looked at the shortcode and don't see anything on my end. Does anyone see the issue here?

I also have my "I'm Looking for a quote" wording overlapping my check box in most browsers. I put a p in and took it out, but I think that might be messing with the code. Anything thoughts on this as well?

Here's the HTML:

```
                <form role="form" id="formspree" method="post">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-name">Your Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" class="contact-email form-control" id="contact-email">
                    </div>
                   <input type="text" name="_gotcha" style="display:none">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-email">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="contact-email form-control" id="contact-email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="sr-only" for="contact-message">Message</label>
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" class="contact-message form-control" id="contact-message" style="height: 168px;width:100%;"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6" style="
text-align: right;
padding-right: 15px;

                            <div class="form-group"><label class="checkbox-inline"><input id="looking_for_quote" type="checkbox" value="quote">I'm Looking For A Quote</label>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg"> Send Message</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

and here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // process the form
    $('form[method=post]').submit(function(event) {
        var email = "mat.mcsales@verizon.net";
       if ($('#looking_for_quote').is(':checked')) {
              email = "orders.mcsales@gmail.com";
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://formspree.io/" + email,
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                message: $('textarea').val(),
                from: $('input[name=name]').val(),
                _reply: $('input[type=email]').val()
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function() {
                alert("Thanks! We'll get back to you soon.");
            }
        });

        // stop the form from submitting the normal way and refreshing the page
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Comment: I figured it out I think.. I changed _reply: $('input[type=email]').val() to email: $('input[name=email]').val()

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out I think.. I changed _reply: $('input[type=email]').val() to email: $('input[name=email]').val()